# How to change the pixel value of a raster dataset which overlaps a polygon featured shapefile in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, shapefile, spatial-analyst

I have a raster data of 1992 and a 'shapefile' of Los Angeles county. I want to reclassify the pixel value of the raster data set to 'no data' or zero in the region where the raster and the 'shapefile' overlaps. I'm using ArcGIS 10.1. I tried using spatial analyst tool> 'reclass'. But I'm not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try the following methodology to get your result:

1. Create a new field (NO_DATA) in your vector file ("No Data Layer") for your no data values records, for example "-9999".
2. Convert your polygon ("No Data Layer") to raster, selecting the same pixel size of the raster data to overlap and the pixel value NO_DATA.

   [Link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000030000000)
3. Mosaic both raster dataset to a new raster, putting your "No Data Layer" on the top of the list and select the option "mosaic_colormap_mode" to FIRST: The pixel value from the first raster dataset in the list will be applied to the output raster mosaic.

   [Link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000)
4. In your new raster, reclasiffy your No data value (for instance, -9999) to "No data"

   [Link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000st000000)

Comment: and the result is i think what i was looking for!!!!